# Canadian/Syrian Dual Citizen

Tags: usa, dual-nationality, canadian-citizens

I moved to Canada from Syria with my family in 2004. I was 10 years old at the time. I am a Canadian citizen and have not visited Syria once since departure. I wish to attend a science conference in the US, would I have problems traveling to the US even though I'm a Canadian citizen? I have seen mixed responses since the travel ban, so I am not sure. Should I call the embassy?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You can travel to the US as can any other Canadian.

The latest version of the travel ban, [a proclamation of September 24, 2017](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/presidential-proclamation-enhancing-vetting-capabilities-processes-detecting-attempted-entry-united-states-terrorists-public-safety-threats/), explicitly does not apply to

> (iv) any dual national of a country designated under section 2 of this proclamation when the individual is traveling on a passport issued by a non-designated country;

(Section 3(b)(iv))

A similar exception exists in [executive order 13780, of March 7, 2017](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/executive-order-protecting-nation-foreign-terrorist-entry-united-states-2/).

See also [CBP's FAQ concerning the executive order, before the proclamation was issued](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/3649/~/executive-order-%28eo%2913780%3A-protecting-the-nation-from-foreign-terrorist-entry):

> 3. What about dual citizens?
>
>    Travelers will be processed according to the travel document they present. For example, if the traveler presents a Canadian passport, the Canadian passport will be used to process that traveler for entry.

The [similar FAQ relating to the proclamation](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/3651/~/executive-order-%28eo%29%3A-proclamation-on-enhancing-vetting-capabilities-and) also quotes the proclamation's section 3 in answering the question "Who does the new Proclamation apply to?"

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that, although dual nationals of Iran, Iraq, Sudan, and Syria, are barred from using the Visa Waiver Program even when using a VWP country passport, Canada is not part of the VWP, and dual nationality of those countries does not affect the ability of Canadians to visit the US without a visa.